# Handling lack of executor memory exception in spark run time

Tags: apache-spark, memory, runtime

I have a spark application and there might be a scenario that unexpected amount of data is flowing into the application and fall into a memory exception at run time.

How can I handle this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the executor runs out of memory.

**Error Msg**:

> Java.lang.OutOfMemory: GC overhead

**Solution**: Increase your executor memory by 
setting up:

```
conf spark.executor.memory= <XY>g
```

Also increase the shuffle partitions as

```
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = <XY>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since memory errors are effectively fatal, and executor memory settings cannot be changed on runtime, there is not much you can do, besides restarting the application with new, higher, memory limits.

Comment: I am not sure if this is more relevant, but can we update the persistence level at runtime of application.  Also what if the application is in production?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running you job again with higher executor memory, try following configuration parameter.

> --conf "spark.executor.memory=16g"

Additionally if you encounter same problem is driver you can try following to increase driver memory.

> --conf "spark.driver.memory=16g"

Hoping this helps.

Cheers !